# How to add a .mm file into the project?

Tags: xcode, object

I need to add a .mm file which contains both ObjectC and C++, I am wondering how to do it using XCode 4?

Comment: Absolutely the same way as with .m

Comment: I tried add an Object-C class, it only creates .m file for me

Comment: I want to know how to add ObjectC++ file from Xcode

Comment: there is no standard template supplied in Xcode 4 for mm. Just rename it to *.mm (Xcode has default rules set for handing obc-c++)

Answer (score 3):

There are absolutely no issues in doing that, just add the **.mm** fle to the project and XCode will compile it as Objective-C++.

The only caveat is that the **.h** associated with that ObjC++ code must not contain any C++ specific code or every file in which that header is included must be **.mm** too.

This because XCode will use different compiler according to the single file, so if a **.m** is found it will try to compile it as plain ObjC and not ObjC++. You can force to compile it with che ObjC++ compiler but I suggest you to follow the principle described or rename other files to **.mm** just to avoid getting things complicated.

Comment: This ceaveat is not an issue with #ifdef __cplusplus and extern "C"

Comment: with extern C you can fix half of the problems. I'm not a fanatic of `#ifdef __cplusplus` though, I guess it's a matter of personal taste, I prefer to avoid it just to avoid clumsy situations.